# How did Aang die?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender, avatar-legend-of-korra

We are shown Aang's children in *The Legend of Korra*, but we were not told how Aang died.

How did he die?

Answer (score 2):

**Natural causes.**

[According to TV Tropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Characters/AvatarTheLastAirbenderAvatarAang), the 100 years Aang spent frozen in ice in the Avatar State shortened his lifespan, causing him to pass away sooner than he otherwise would have. While this is not revealed in the show itself, it is apparently revealed in "supplementary materials", though what those are, I unfortunately don't know.

To quote the site's entry for "Cast from Lifespan":

> Aang's lifespan was shortened due to spending a century in a trance state, after being trapped in an iceberg for 99 years. He passed away at the biological age of 66. By comparison, Avatar Kyoshi lived to 230.

Answer (score 0):

Aang appears to have died of natural causes in his mid-60s. Most avatars live to be very old indeed (Avatars Kyoshi and Yangchen both made it beyond their bicentennials) but according to the show's makers Aang used up his lifeforce keeping him alive inside the glacier.

> **Wall Street Journal:** *If there's a new Avatar, that means Aang has passed on. If he died around age 70, isn't that pretty young for an
> Avatar?*
>
> **Konietzko:** *You gotta keep in mind that he was frozen in a state of suspended animation for 100 years, so he kind of burned up some of
> his extra Avatar time.*
>
> <sup><sub>[Wall Street Journal interview with Bryke, July 21, 2010](https://avatar.fandom.com/wiki/Transcript:Wall_Street_Journal_interview_with_Bryke,_July_21,_2010)</sub></sup>

One of the webgames ([*Welcome to Republic City*](https://avatar.fandom.com/wiki/Welcome_to_Republic_City_(game))) that accompanied the new series suggests that he died age 66.

> [image]
>
> Before Aang's death, he instructed the White Lotus to protect the next Avatar incarnation. **At the age of 66, Avatar Aang passed.** The Avatar spirit is reincarnated as a girl from the Southern Water Tribe... and the Legend of Korra begins.